# Toshiba Laptop screen flickering and now won't turn on

Tags: laptop, display

Three days ago my laptop screen started to display small black flickering rectangles spread across the screen and the display it self is messed up. I turned off the laptop and on again and everything was fine. This happened again yesterday again but this time i turned off the laptop and on again but the screen never showed anything, it's just black as if the laptop is turned off. I tried using another secondary screen but also there was nothing shown there as well. 
A photo of the screen when it was flickering is here:

[image]
Any idea what could be causing the problem ?

EDIT: My laptop version is Toshiba T135

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ribbon cable linking the display to the laptop body is defect.